Get first row of subquery using LEFT JOIN - SQL-92
Transaction



TRANID
ID
VALUE




A-01
23
Q


B-01
50
E


B-02
80
R


B-03
81
T



TransactionLine



CREATEDFROM
ID




NULL
23


23
50


23
80


23
81



I want the value of the first secondary transaction:



TRANID
CHILD_TRANID
CHILD_VALUE




A-01
B-01
E



I get error Column:TRANSACTION.TRANID not found.
SELECT
    TR.TRANID,
    TRP.CHILD_TRANID,
        TRP.CHILD_VALUE
FROM
    TRANSACTION TR
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            TOP 1
            _TR.TRANID AS TRANID_FWD,
            _TR.VALUE,
            _TRC.TRANID AS TRANID_PREV
        FROM
            TRANSACTION _TR
            LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONLINE _TL ON _TL.ID = _TR.ID
            LEFT JOIN TRANSACTION _TRC ON _TL.CREATEDFROM = _TRC.ID
        WHERE _TRC.TRANID = TR.TRANID
    ) TRP ON TRP.TRANID_PREV = TR.TRANID
WHERE
    TR.TRANID = 'A-01';

What other approach can I use?
What is wrong with my query?

To achieve the desired result, try this approach using ROW_NUMBER() to rank child transactions and select the first occurrence:
WITH RankedTransactions AS (
    SELECT 
        TR.TRANID AS TRANID_PREV,
        TRL.ID AS CHILD_ID,
        CHILD.TRANID AS CHILD_TRANID,
        CHILD.VALUE AS CHILD_VALUE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TR.TRANID ORDER BY CHILD.TRANID) AS row_num
    FROM 
        TRANSACTION TR
        LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONLINE TRL ON TR.ID = TRL.CREATEDFROM
        LEFT JOIN TRANSACTION CHILD ON TRL.ID = CHILD.ID
)
SELECT 
    TRANID_PREV AS TRANID,
    CHILD_TRANID,
    CHILD_VALUE
FROM 
    RankedTransactions
WHERE 
    TRANID_PREV = 'A-01' AND row_num = 1;

Here you can find the offical documention of Partion By [ Documentation ]

Thank you very much for your answer, but unfortunately I am working with a database based on SQL-92, I have been reviewing the documentation of that standard and apparently CTEs are not supported, so they cannot be used in the query, thats why I tried subqueries
